# A first-order linear pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I am interested in solving the following pde $$a u v \partial_u f - (b + u v) \partial_v f = 0$$ over the reals, possibly with some restriction on the range of $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ if necessary. I only need the characteristic curves, so there's no need to consider boundary conditions.

I was under the impression that all first order linear pdes were solvable algorithmically by the method of characteristics in terms of integrals of the coefficient functions in front of each derivative. However I gave this equation to Mathematica and it was not able to find a solution.

Did I misunderstand something here? Does this equation have some feature which means that it's not possible to solve it using characteristics?
Is someone able to provide a solution to the equation?

Answer (score 1):

$$a u v \partial_u f - (b + u v) \partial_v f = 0.$$
$f(u,v)$ is the unknown function.

Charpit-Lagrange :
$$\frac{du}{auv}=\frac{dv}{-(b+uv)}$$
$$(b+uv(u))du+auv(u)dv=0$$
This is a non linear first order ODE very difficult to solve. With the invaluable help of WolframAlpha the solution is obtained on the form of an implicit equation :
$$\sqrt{2\pi}\:\text{erf}\left(\frac{av+u}{\sqrt{2ab}}\right)+2i\frac{\sqrt{ab}}{u}\exp\left(-\frac{(av+u)^2}{2ab}\right)=c$$
The constant can be real or complex.

The general solution of the PDE expressed on implicit form $f(u,v)=\Phi(c)$ is :
$$f(u,v)=\Phi\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\:\text{erf}\left(\frac{av+u}{\sqrt{2ab}}\right)+2i\frac{\sqrt{ab}}{u}\exp\left(-\frac{(av+u)^2}{2ab}\right)\right)$$
$\Phi$ is an arbitrary function (real or complex).

It is doubtfull that the function $\Phi$ can be analytically determined according to some boundary condition. In practice, better rely on numerical methods of solving.

Comment: Thanks for your solution this is nice. However I'm working only over the real numbers, is there some way to give a solution without the imaginary part that you've introduced?

Comment: Don't ask for too much. Check the solution to see if there is not a mistake. Sorry I have no more time available.

Comment: In the question it is not specified if $a$ and/or $b$ are positive or negative. Complex variables lead to a wider domain of solutions. Eventualy complex function $\Phi$ might produce real solutions with complex argument. One cannot say without boundary conitions.

Comment: I think it should be possible to give a purely real solution for $a b >0$, I don't think this is asking for too much.  In the end I need to set $f=0$ so I don't need a boundary condition; it's ok for me to take $\Phi(x) = x$ and consider only the characteristic curves

Comment: OK. Try it. But you should check the solution to see if there is no mistake into it (put it into the PDE and see if it agrees).